# How to enable OLTP while creating new partition table in Oracle 11g

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I am getting following errors while creating partion table:

```
SQL EXCEPTION
ANSI-92 SQL State  : null
Vendor error code  : 17081
java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during batching: ORA-14464: Compression Type not specified

java.sql.BatchUpdateException: error occurred during batching: ORA-14464: Compression Type not specified
```

below is the code which is used to create partiotion table without compression we want to enable the compression for oltp for this kind of table:

```
CREATE
  TABLE TOPD_UID
  (
    OTYPE    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    RELEASE  VARCHAR2(16 BYTE),
    OUID     NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    FUID     NUMBER(38,0) NOT NULL ENABLE,
    OEXID    VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
    LD_OEXID VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
    FTYPE    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    OFN      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
    CUR      NUMBER(1,0),
    REFDATE DATE,
    DISCOVERYDATE DATE,
    CUSTOMER         NUMBER(1,0),
    VENDOR           VARCHAR2(12 BYTE) DEFAULT 'EVOLIUM',
    PLANNED          NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
    FORECAST         NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
    TUNABLE          NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1,
    TUNABLE_DESC     VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    TUNABLE_OWNER    VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    TUNING_REF       NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
    TUNING_REF_DESC  VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    TUNING_REF_OWNER VARCHAR2(128 BYTE),
    POST_IT          VARCHAR2(4000 BYTE),
    PLANNED_OFN      VARCHAR2(256 BYTE),
    SUB_OTYPE        NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
    COMMERCIAL       NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1,
    ISMONITORED      NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0
  )
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT
  )
  TABLESPACE MUSE PARTITION BY LIST
  (
    OTYPE
  )
  (
    PARTITION P_EXCELL2G VALUES
    (
      'EXCELL2G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_ECELL2G VALUES
    (
      'ECELL2G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_OMC VALUES
    (
      'OMC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_ECELL3G VALUES
    (
      'ECELL3G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_NETWORK VALUES
    (
      'NETWORK'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_FUTRAN VALUES
    (
      'FUTRAN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_EUTRAN VALUES
    (
      'EUTRAN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_GERAN VALUES
    (
      'GERAN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_UTRAN VALUES
    (
      'UTRAN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_EBSCELL VALUES
    (
      'EBSCELL'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_WRAN VALUES
    (
      'WRAN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_REMOTECELL3G VALUES
    (
      'REMOTECELL3G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION DEFERRED PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE( INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT) TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_N7LS VALUES
    (
      'N7LS'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_BTS_BSC_LAPD VALUES
    (
      'BTS_BSC_LAPD'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_SGSN VALUES
    (
      'SGSN'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_MFS VALUES
    (
      'MFS'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_BTS_D VALUES
    (
      'BTS_D'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_SS7SL VALUES
    (
      'SS7SL'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_TRXTS VALUES
    (
      'TRXTS'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_ECELLLTE VALUES
    (
      'ECELLLTE'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_SGSN_IP_NSVC VALUES
    (
      'SGSN_IP_NSVC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_GSL VALUES
    (
      'GSL'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_SGSN_ITF VALUES
    (
      'SGSN_ITF'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_TRX VALUES
    (
      'TRX'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_TRAFFIC_ZONE VALUES
    (
      'TRAFFIC_ZONE'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_FHS VALUES
    (
      'FHS'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_MGW VALUES
    (
      'MGW'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_N7SL VALUES
    (
      'N7SL'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_BSC VALUES
    (
      'BSC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_X25 VALUES
    (
      'X25'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_PVC VALUES
    (
      'PVC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_MSC VALUES
    (
      'MSC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_ABISGROUP VALUES
    (
      'ABISGROUP'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_BTS VALUES
    (
      'BTS'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_CELL2G VALUES
    (
      'CELL2G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_BEARERCHANNEL VALUES
    (
      'BEARERCHANNEL'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_EXCELL3G VALUES
    (
      'EXCELL3G'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_TC_RACK VALUES
    (
      'TC_RACK'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_TRNC VALUES
    (
      'TRNC'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_NRI VALUES
    (
      'NRI'
    )
    SEGMENT CREATION IMMEDIATE PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
    NOCOMPRESS LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
    MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
    BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
    TABLESPACE MUSE ,
    PARTITION P_GPRS_CELL VALUES
    (
      'GPRS_CELL'
    )
```

please help me to resolve this problem.

thanks

Comment: You mean OLTP compression right? Please show the SQL statement you're executing.

Comment: I WANT TO CREATE SIMILAR NEW TABLE:

Answer (score 3):

this error can occur if you don't specify the compression type correctly.

eg if you put quotes in:

```
   SUB_OTYPE        NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0,
    COMMERCIAL       NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 1,
    ISMONITORED      NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0
  )
    COMPRESS FOR 'ALL OPERATIONS'
  PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE
  (
    INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE
    DEFAULT
  )
```

you'd get:

```
    COMPRESS FOR 'ALL OPERATIONS'
                 *
ERROR at line 31:
ORA-14464: Compression Type not specified
```

whereas, without it, it would work

```
 29      ISMONITORED      NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT 0
 30    )
 31      COMPRESS FOR ALL OPERATIONS
 32    PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255 STORAGE
 33    (
 34      INITIAL 65536 BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE
 35      DEFAULT
 36    )
 37    PARTITION BY LIST
 38    (
 39      OTYPE
 40    )
 41    (
...
381      PARTITION P_NRI VALUES
382      (
383        'NRI'
384      )
385       PCTFREE 10 PCTUSED 40 INITRANS 1 MAXTRANS 255
386       LOGGING STORAGE(INITIAL 65536 NEXT 1048576 MINEXTENTS 1
387      MAXEXTENTS 2147483645 PCTINCREASE 0 FREELISTS 1 FREELIST GROUPS 1
388      BUFFER_POOL DEFAULT FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT CELL_FLASH_CACHE DEFAULT)
389       ,
390      PARTITION P_GPRS_CELL VALUES
391      (
392        'GPRS_CELL'
393      )
394     );

Table created.

SQL> select partition_name, compression, compress_for from user_tab_partitions where table_name = 'TOPD_UID2';

PARTITION_NAME                 COMPRESS COMPRESS_FOR
------------------------------ -------- ------------
P_EXCELL2G                     ENABLED  OLTP
P_ECELL2G                      ENABLED  OLTP
P_OMC                          ENABLED  OLTP
P_ECELL3G                      ENABLED  OLTP
P_NETWORK                      ENABLED  OLTP
P_FUTRAN                       ENABLED  OLTP
P_EUTRAN                       ENABLED  OLTP
```

Comment: @gaurav_376 you attempted to edit my answer saying you wanted to keep NOCOMPRESS whilst still wanting OLTP compression on the new table. this is nonsense. either you want to compress or you don't. please elaborate on why the above answer (as you wanted a new similar table) isn't what you are after..as a comment please not editing my answer to add your notes. what I was attempting to show was why you can get that error and the proper snytax for OLTP compression.

Comment: ps the only reason i removed the deferred bit in my sample is that at the time I wrote it I was testing on 11.2.0.1 where that feature isn't available. but its not relevant to your issue (you can keep those in on 11.2.0.2+). if you want to keep NOCOMPRESS in on some partitions, feel free.